# strange characters in DNS answer

Tags: pointers, url, dns

I have found example of DNS client in c:
https://www.binarytides.com/dns-query-code-in-c-with-linux-sockets/
And I don't understand one thing in function ReadName(). There *reader is pointer to start of DNS answer, where is URL who’s IP address we wish to find.
I don't understand condition which is there:

```
if(*reader>=192)
{
    offset = (*reader)*256 + *(reader+1) - 49152; //49152 = 11000000 00000000 ;)
    reader = buffer + offset - 1;
    jumped = 1; //we have jumped to another location so counting wont go up!
}
else
{
    name[p++]=*reader;
}
```

What it mean, when some char of URL is greater than 192? And what exactly we do (in condition)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "strange" characters in the DNS.

The code you show is related to pointers and how names are compressed in DNS packets.

You need to read [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), and specifically §4.1.4 "Message compression".

If a two bytes sequence starts with the first two bit set (that is decimal value 128 + 64 = 192 for one byte), then the rest is a pointer to another place in the message where the name is stored.

This is exactly what the code above does.

Answer (score 0):

> where is URL who’s IP address we wish to find

Hostname (DNS does deal with URLs) was entered from stdin and was an argument of `ngethostbyname` function.

Comparison with 192 is related to non ASCII domain names.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Why exactly is there comparison with 192?

Comment: "Comparison with 192 is related to non ASCII domain names."  absolutely not! First there are no "non ASCII domain names", since all domain names are encoded with Punycode in a LDH fashion so in DNS packets all domain names are ASCII (other characters can appear than LDH, the DNS is 8-bit clean, it is just that for hostnames it is LDH). Then this specific value of 192 is explained in the RFC (see my answser for full details); this is related to names compression and pointers, and happens possibly for any name, ASCII or not.